# How execute a Java jar file from Oracle PL/SQL with parameters?

Tags: java, oracle, jar, plsql, oracle11g

I have a DB with jobs defined. Those jobs have to invoke a jar file passing some params needed by the java classes inside the jar file.

I have found some examples where simple classes were loaded in stored procedures in the Oracle 11g database, but is it possible to call a jar file passing params from a pl/sql? Any other better way to do this?

I am using Oracle 11g and Java 1.6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct then yes.. put before your script

SET DEFINE OFF

CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED....

Your code...

at the end...
/

SET DEFINE ON

back again.. or you can just go editor - execute statement, not execute as script.
hope helps..